# model fields are not created django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    auther=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    body=models.TextField(default="")
```

0001_inital.py

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Blog',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
    ),
]
```

cmd

```
$> python manage.py migrate
$> python manage.py makemigrations
   Migrations for 'first_app':
     first_app\migrations\0002_auto_20210531_1214.py
       - Add field auther to blog
       - Add field body to blog
       - Add field title to blog
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fields not created". Seems like django has no problem creating the tables and columns

Answer (score 0):

After making the migrations, you need to run  `python manage.py migrate` to apply the migrations to database.

If you have not registered your model in `admin.py`, you need to do so.Write the following code in `admin.py`

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Blog
    admin.site.register(Blog)
```

Comment: after run python manage.py migrate   nothing change

Comment: What was the output?

Comment: migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Blog',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),

Comment: This seems to be the contents of migrations file. What was the output after executing ` python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, first_app, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: Or You might have not registered your model in admin.py

Comment: I have registered

Comment: from django.contrib import admin


from first_app.models import Blog
admin.site.register(Blog)

Comment: Then try deleting the migrations folder from the app and db.sqlite3
then retry python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate